# Не работает SNMP в Java процедуре

Tags: java, oracle, oracle19c, права-доступа

Пытаюсь запустить следующую Java процедуру в Oracle 19с JVM. Данная процедура должна запросить по SNMP у принтера определенный OID и вернуть его значение.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.snmp4j.CommunityTarget;
import org.snmp4j.PDU;
import org.snmp4j.Snmp;
import org.snmp4j.Target;
import org.snmp4j.TransportMapping;
import org.snmp4j.event.ResponseEvent;
import org.snmp4j.mp.SnmpConstants;
import org.snmp4j.smi.Address;
import org.snmp4j.smi.GenericAddress;
import org.snmp4j.smi.OID;
import org.snmp4j.smi.OctetString;
import org.snmp4j.smi.VariableBinding;
import org.snmp4j.transport.DefaultUdpTransportMapping;


public class Get_ink_levels_devices {

Snmp snmp = null;
String address = null;

/**
* Constructor
* @param add
*/
public Get_ink_levels_devices(String add)
{
address = add;
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
/**
* Port 161 is used for Read and Other operations
* Port 162 is used for the trap generation
*/
Get_ink_levels_devices client = new Get_ink_levels_devices("udp:192.168.115.77/161");
client.start();
/**
* OID - .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0 => SysDec
* OID - .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0 => SysName
*.1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0
*.1.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.2.1.3.1
* => MIB explorer will be usefull here, as discussed in previous article
*/
String sysDescr = client.getAsString(new OID("1.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.2.1.3.1"));
System.out.println(sysDescr);
}

private void start() throws IOException {
TransportMapping transport = new DefaultUdpTransportMapping();
snmp = new Snmp(transport);
// Do not forget this line!
transport.listen();
}

/**
* Method which takes a single OID and returns the response from the agent as a String.
* @param oid
* @return
* @throws IOException
*/
public String getAsString(OID oid) throws IOException {
    ResponseEvent event = get(new OID[]{oid});
    if(event.getResponse() != null){
        return event.getResponse().get(0).getVariable().toString();
    } else {
        return "no target";
    }
}

/**
* This method is capable of handling multiple OIDs
* @param oids
* @return
* @throws IOException
*/
public ResponseEvent get(OID oids[]) throws IOException {
PDU pdu = new PDU();
for (OID oid : oids) {
pdu.add(new VariableBinding(oid));
}
pdu.setType(PDU.GET);
ResponseEvent event = snmp.send(pdu, getTarget(), null);
if(event != null) {
return event;
}
throw new RuntimeException("GET timed out");
}

/**
* This method returns a Target, which contains information about
* where the data should be fetched and how.
* @return
*/
private Target getTarget() {
Address targetAddress = GenericAddress.parse(address);
CommunityTarget target = new CommunityTarget();
target.setCommunity(new OctetString("public"));
target.setAddress(targetAddress);
target.setRetries(2);
target.setTimeout(5000);
target.setVersion(SnmpConstants.version1);
return target;
}

}
```

После компиляции загружаю с `loadjava`. Вызываю так:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Procedure Test_ink AS LANGUAGE JAVA NAME 'Get_ink_levels_devices.main(java.lang.String[])';
/
set serveroutput on; 
call dbms_java.set_output(1000000); 
exec Test_ink;
```

После этого она замирает, и через некоторое время выдает `no target` и все. 
При этом в консоли возвращает значение.

Пропробовал WireShark, показывает, что пакеты приходят и уходят, но процедура почему-то не принимает ответ.

Добавил различные разрешения для Java например:

```
dbms_java.grant_permission (grantee => 'ADMIN',permission_type => 'java.net.SocketPermission',permission_name => 'localhost',permission_action => 'accept,connect,listen,resolve');
dbms_java.grant_permission (grantee => 'ADMIN',permission_type => 'java.net.SocketPermission',permission_name => '*',permission_action => 'accept,connect,listen,resolve');
dbms_java.grant_permission (grantee => 'ADMIN',permission_type => 'java.net.SocketPermission',permission_name => '192.168.115.77',permission_action => 'accept,connect,listen,resolve');
```

, но процедура не хочет правильно выполняться. То есть, при выполнении из консоли она возвращает значение `OID`, но при запуске в БД возвращает `no target`, как будто ответ не доходит.

Не могу понять, это связано с отсутствием необходимых Java разрешений или с чем-то ещё? Если дело в разрешениях, то какие нужны? Я уже разные пробовал: и `java.net.NetPermission` и `java.net.SocketPermission`.
Я правильно понимаю, что при любой нехватке разрешений будет исключение, даже если процедура отправила пакет, но не может  получить ответный из-за нехватки разрешений, и должно возникнуть исключение а не просто штатное завершение программы как будто хост не доступен.Просто тогда не понятно, пакеты уходят я вижу их в WireShark, но почему то процедура не может их принять словно Oracle блокирует, не пропускает их. Собственно это и есть воспроизводимый пример, надо только скачать отсюда библиотеку www.snmp4j.org "snmp4j-2.8.3.jar" загрузить её в Oracle  и после уже загружать процедуру.

Вообщем попробовал выполнить удаленную отладку данной процедуры через SQL Developer с использованием CALL DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP.CONNECT_TCP.В результате выпало сообщение
`The debbuger has hit an exception breackpoint, but it cannot find the source file.Unable to find source file for package java.net,filename DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java.Project IdeConnections%23OEC.jpr and its dependencies have already been searched.`

Как я понимаю он не может найти файл с пакетом java так как он встроен в саму СУБД Oracle так же было сообщение

```
Exception breakpoint: DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:157, java.net.SocketException, getsockopt() failed, errno = 0
Для вызова getsockopt или setsockopt был указан неизвестный, недопустимый или неподдерживаемый параметр или уровень.
```

После этого я нашел в интернете, похожую процедуру

```
    import java.io.IOException;
import org.snmp4j.CommunityTarget;
import org.snmp4j.PDU;
import org.snmp4j.Snmp;
import org.snmp4j.smi.*;
import org.snmp4j.mp.*;
import org.snmp4j.transport.DefaultUdpTransportMapping;
import org.snmp4j.event.ResponseEvent;
import org.snmp4j.util.*;


public class Collector1  {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            Snmp snmp4j =  new Snmp(new DefaultUdpTransportMapping());
            snmp4j.listen();
            Address add = new UdpAddress("192.168.115.77/161");
            CommunityTarget target = new CommunityTarget();
            target.setAddress(add);
            target.setTimeout(1500);
            target.setRetries(3);
            target.setCommunity(new OctetString("public"));
            target.setVersion(SnmpConstants.version1);
            PDU request = new PDU();
            request.setType(PDU.GET);
            OID oid= new OID("1.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.2.1.3.1");
            request.add(new VariableBinding(oid));
            PDU responsePDU=null;
            ResponseEvent responseEvent;
            responseEvent = snmp4j.send(request, target);

           if (responseEvent.getResponse() != null)
            {
                String sysDescr = responseEvent.getResponse().get(0).getVariable().toString();
                System.out.println(sysDescr);
            }
                else
            {            
                 System.out.println("no target");                     
            }

   }

}
```

Использующую туже библиотеку snmp4j-2.8.3. Тот же результат и та же ошибка при отладке SQL Developer, при этом в консоли cmd все выполняется нормально. Наконец я взял простую процедуру, которая просто отправляет UDP диаграмму на заданный адрес и порт

```
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;


public class udp {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(udp.send("192.168.112.77","53","Test"));
    }

    public static String send(String ip,String port,String msg){
        try{
            int int_port=Integer.parseInt(port);    
            DatagramSocket ds = new DatagramSocket();
            DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(msg.getBytes(), msg.length(), InetAddress.getByName(ip), int_port);
            ds.send(dp);
            ds.close();
            return "Successfully";
        }catch(Exception e){
            return "Failed";
        }
    }
}
```

И в случае успеха выводит сообщение и опять таки в консоли все нормально, при выполнении в базе данных возвращает Failed. В SQL Developer опять та же ошибка. Я не разбираюсь в Java и просто пробую,но исходя из всего этого, можно ли предположить, что это какой-то баг в Oracle JVM при работе с UDP, у меня версия JDK 1.8.0_201 в Oracle или же все таки проблема в разрешениях Java, но я не представляю в каких, так как разрешил все что можно в плане работы Java с сеть.

Comment: А как вы её вызываете? Вообще, если не хватает разрешений, то возврата не будет, это исключение.

Comment: Пожалуйста, не в коментарий, правте вопрос. А БД установленна на этой же машине?

Comment: простите, не понял, отвечать в вопросе, да это виртуалка Windows Server 2019, на ней Oracle 19 c и JDK 14.В JDK компилирую, потом заливаю в Oracle.

Comment: На счёт разрешений: при их нехватке будет исключение. Пока не встречал, чтобы эти исключения где-то перехватывались. Делайте [mcve](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Простите, вы не могли посмотреть мое дополнение к вопросу.

Comment: В последнем примере вы подавили исключение вместо того, чтобы посмотреть, что за ошибка.

Comment: Простите, а что, мне надо было сделать, что б посмотреть ошибку. После запуска отладки в логе сразу появляется Exception breakpoint: DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:157, java.net.SocketException, getsockopt() failed, errno = 0
Для вызова getsockopt или setsockopt был указан неизвестный, недопустимый или неподдерживаемый параметр или уровень.

Comment: То есть, вы утверждааете, что последний пример работает в консоли, но не работает с внутренней JVM в БД. Это так?  Так как вы не предоставили mvce, потребуется время, чтобы всё воспроизвести. Не могу его выделить "сейчас же", посмотрю попозже.

Comment: Да.Не только последний, но и все примеры работают в консоли правильно и не правильно работают с внутренней JVM.Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Простой пример, который отправляет UDP датаграмм, работает с внутренней JVM в БД:

```java
create or replace and compile java source named UdpTest as
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Udp {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        System.out.println (">>> send " + Arrays.toString (args) + " ...");
        System.out.println (Udp.send (args[0], Integer.parseInt (args[1]), args[2]));
    }
    public static String send (String url, int port, String msg) {
        try {
            DatagramSocket ds = new DatagramSocket ();
            DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket (msg.getBytes (), msg.length (), InetAddress.getByName (url), port);
            ds.send (dp);
            ds.close ();
            return "Successfully";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace ();
            return "Failure"; 
        }
    }
}
/
create or replace procedure sendUdp (url varchar2, port char, msg varchar2) as
    language java name 'Udp.main (java.lang.String[])';
/
```

Следующие разрешения были выданы (под пользователем SYS):

```sql
exec -
dbms_java.grant_permission ('SH', 'SYS:java.net.SocketPermission', 'localhost:0', 'listen,resolve'); -
dbms_java.grant_permission ('SH', 'SYS:java.net.SocketPermission', '127.0.0.1:53', 'connect,resolve');
```

**Важно**: новые разрешения не действуют в текущей сессии. Поэтому, в новой сессии:

```sql
set serveroutput on size unlimited
exec dbms_java.set_output(10000)

exec sendUdp ('localhost', 53, 'abc')

>>> send [localhost, 53, abc] ...
Successfully
```

Проверено с `tcpdump` и в консоли:

```sh
~# tcpdump -n -ilo udp port 53
22:25:37.166568 IP 127.0.0.1.36465 > 127.0.0.1.53: domain [length 3 < 12] (invalid)

$ javac Udp.java
$ java -cp . Udp localhost 53 abc
>>> send [localhost, 53, abc] ...
Successfully
```

Comment: Спасибо, удалил все свои разрешения добавил, все как у вас, единственное загрузил loadjava ой .Запускаю exec sendUdp('localhost', 53, 'abc'); Вывод: java.net.SocketException: getsockopt() failed, errno = 2 ??? ?????? getsockopt ??? setsockopt ??? ?????? ???????????, ???????????? ??? ???????????????? ???????? ??? ???????. at java.net.DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.socketClose(Native Method) Failure

Comment: Ну для начала, поставте правильное окружение, чтобы вывод ошибки был понятен.

Comment: Простите, а вы не знаете, какое правильное значение для LC_ALL для Windows попробовал ru_RU.CP866, но поп прежнему ????

Comment: Нет, не знаю, у меня нет виндоуза. Вроде там нет LC_ALL, а что то такое chcp. Попробуйте вернутся на англ., как то так `set nls_lang=`

Comment: Вы знаете, это не важно, так как ошибка повторяет предыдущую а именно "Для вызова getsockopt или setsockopt был указан неизвестный, недопустимый или неподдерживаемый параметр или уровень." нечего не поменялось, к сожалению, да же не представляю от чего это может, возможно какая-то не совместимость с Windows Server 2019. А какая у вас версия Oracle и версия JDK внутренняя?

Comment: Таже версия, что и у вас: 19.3.0.0, JDK естествено тоже совпадает. Попробуйте всё таки  повторить пример выше, без всяких изменений, в англ. окружении без кирилицы.

Comment: при nls_lang=AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8 ├Д├л├┐ ├в├╗├з├о├в├а getsockopt ├и├л├и setsockopt ├б├╗├л ├│├к├а├з├а├н ├н├е├и├з├в├е├▒├▓├н├╗├й, ├н├е├д├о├п├│├▒├▓├и├м├╗├й ├и├л├и ├н├е├п├о├д├д├е├░├ж├и├в├а├е├м├╗├й ├п├а├░├а├м├е├▓├░ ├и├л├и ├│├░├о├в├е├н├╝. Я думаю вряд ли разберемся.Можно ли перенести тему в Java раздел, может там смогут что-то посоветовать?

Comment: Куда перенести? У вопроса и так метка java. Прочтите мой предыдущий комментарий более внимательно.

Comment: Да я вас понял, повторил полностью скомпилировал не в консоле, а прям в JVM create or replace and compile java source named UdpTest as , потом создал процедуру дал разрешения при запуске все то же. То есть вопрос видят Java программисты , но просто не отвечают, то есть его нельзя как-то поднять в поиске не знаю.Конечно, можно взять другую ос в виртуалке поднять там Oracle попробовать, но не хочется столько времени тратить просто.Не думал, что столкнусь с такой проблемой.

Comment: Всё не так безнадёжно, первый результат ведь достигнут. У вас есть теперь провереный, минимальный и воспроизводимый пример.  Вы поняли, что snmp4j тут не причём. Привлечь внимание вы можете правкой вопроса. Мало кому захочется читать метр вопроса с двумя метрами комментариев. Удалите оттуда всё ненужное - только пример, вывод в консоли без ошибки,  полный трейс ошибки из БД, и всё.  Стоит ли переустановить БД под нормальной ОС, это вам решать, я бы сказал - если нужно для работы, то да, стоит.

Comment: Вообщем поставил на Windows Server 2016 виртуалку все с 0, тажа ошибка опять.Но я обратил внимание в файле INIT.ORA есть строка dispatchers='(PROTOCOL=TCP) (SERVICE=OECXDB)', протокол TCP может здесь нужен ещё UDP или нет, не знаете?

Comment: Нет, параметр dispatchers это нечто другое. Так какая целевая ОС теперь?

Comment: Windows Server 2016 Datacenter 10.0.14393

Comment: И что вы хотели этим достичь? Думал вы хотели обычную ОС поставить. Я же показал, что пример на ОС отличной от виндоус прекрасно работает.

Comment: Да собственно, нечего, я делал просто для портфолио тестовую базу, которая будет работать с картриджами, практически все было готово, и просто решил попробовать добавить ещё java процедуру, и столкнулся сразу с этой ошибкой, поскольку у меня база была на Windows Server 2019, я просто подумал что возможно на 2016 заработает, но увы ошибся, а обычную ОС вы имеете виду Red Hat например, просто oracle вроде не на любой linux можно поставить? Просто тогда получается, что эта ошибка вызвана какой-то не совместимостью JVM и ОС Windows, что ли?

Comment: Список сертифицированных дистрибутивов есть в мануале по установке. У меня  дистрибутив не сертифицирован, но тоже не беда. Основное отличие JVM под консолью и в БД это пользователь ОС, под которым они запускаются.

Comment: Вообщем , после поиска в интернете данной ошибки "Для вызова getsockopt или setsockopt был указан неизвестный, недопустимый или не поддерживаемый параметр или уровень." , прихожу к выводу возможно не верному, что некому методу или функции socketSetOption в недрах java передается неправильное значение или лишнее и генерируется исключение, не знаю в каких версиях Windows Server ,это происходит, но суть в том что ошибка возникает именно в JVM , а не в JDK общей. Не буду оформлять это как ответ, так как не уверен, но другой причины я не знаю, если кто-то найдет, пусть напишет.

Comment: А какой ответ вы можете дать? Всё что вы написали в последнем комментарии стоит в вашем вопросе, ничего нового. Всё, что вы можете сделать для решеня проблемы я написал в этом [комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1116124/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-snmp-%d0%b2-java-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b5/1117984?noredirect=1#comment1930930_1117984). Тоже самое касается вашего вопроса на enSO.

Comment: Я имею виду, что на текущий момент, я для себя в последнем комментарии и даю возможный ответ, но поскольку у меня нет в нем уверенности, я не оформляю его как ответ, не знаю стоит ли, к сожалению не могу столько времени уделять поиску решения данной проблемы, поэтому пока оставляю, если вдруг потом кто-то натолкнется на вопрос и сможет дать ответ или я сам найду решение, то дам полноценной ответ. Пока вижу только вариант попробовать в Linux дистрибутиве и не сомневаюсь,что там все заработает, но что б проверить для windows нужен, кто-то кто воспроизведет это на windows системе.